# Swift How to set color of a single TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I tried

```
if(indexPath.row == colorIndex){
   cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

and this

```
func setup(item: MPMediaItem){
    self.textLabel?.text = item.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as? String
    if(currentPlayingItem == item){
        self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

It's a method inside my custom UITableCell class

But as you can see on GIF other cells are also affected. How can I avoid this so only the one with index, let's say 3 gets colored?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically set the non-red rows to black (or whatever the non-red color is):

```
if(indexPath.row == colorIndex){
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
}
else {
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the specific data to be colored then this `color attribute` should be in the data itself.

```
struct Item {
  ... // other members 
  var preferredColor:UIColor? // I'd use hex instead so you could transform your hex code to UIColor 
}

var items = [Item]() // array 

// cellForRowAt
let dataAtCell = items[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.textColor = dataAtCell.preferredColor ?? .black // if you don't have a color for that cell then the default color is black
```